# Deleting CoreData journaling mode not migrating to new store

Tags: core-data, ios7, magicalrecord

Since MagicalRecord 3.0 has not been released yet, I upgraded to 2.3 and tried to "turn off" journaling mode. This is my code:

```
    //  Code to disable journaling mode
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *urlString = [applicationDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"saori.sqlite"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString];
NSDictionary *options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}};
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
[psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil  URL:url options:options error:nil];
```

What's happening is it's not only NOT turning off journaling mode, but it creates an entirely new (read *empty*)  CoreData store *with* journaling.

Is there anything I can do outside of MR 3.0 so the contents of the journaled store are migrated to a new CoreData store without journaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MagicalRecord 3.0 will not change whether this works or not. This is a CoreData feature. MR 3.0 will provide you a way to specify options for adding a particular store, so it's less code. But the fact that Journalling or WAL mode are an issue, this is fundamental to how CoreData itself works. And in that case, moving to MR3 probably won't help you.